# How to suppress "Setting display..." in Abaqus scripting

Tags: python, abaqus

I have many abaqus plugins that perform actions in Abaqus CAE through a scripting interface. For many actions after they are executed Abaqus performs some display refresh procedures that take some time. If the models are small and the script does not do too much it is alright. However, e.g. one of my scripts takes a part and replicates it in the assembly at the coordinates specified by user's CSV file. Sometimes there might be up to 2000 such replications. In this case it takes forever to complete the procedure and most of the time you only see "Setting display..."

Furthermore this "Setting display..." overwrites your scripts' progress (milestone) so it is difficult to see how far the script had advanced.

Is there any way to suspend this display updating behavior until the script finishes? Maybe there is a hack that you could redefine abaqus update function until the script is done or something because according to the manual the only thing you can do is to prevent the updating of the color scheme, but that does not help at all.

Any tips will be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: To clarify I used folowing methods on a viewport object with no vain:

```
disableRefresh()
disableColorCodeUpdates()
```

What does the `disableColorCodeUpdates()` do is quite clear and the benefit is apparent when color coding is used in the model viewport. However, I see no difference between using and not using `disableRefresh()`.

EDIT: Sorry for such a long wait, only now I had a chance to get back at abaqus. Here is a simple example script that takes a part and places it in assembly:

```
import random
modelName='Model-1'
partName='Part-1'
noInst=1000

i = 0
lists = []
for i in range(noInst):
    lists.append([random.random()*10,random.random()*10,random.random()*10])

totalParts = len(lists)
session.Viewport(name='Viewport: 2', origin=(6.63750028610229, 
        20.7638893127441), width=335.746887207031, height=149.77685546875)
session.viewports['Viewport: 2'].makeCurrent()
session.viewports['Viewport: 2'].maximize()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].restore()

for n,l in enumerate(lists):
    milestone('Replicating parts', 'parts', n+1, totalParts)
    a = mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly
    p = mdb.models[modelName].parts[partName]
    a.Instance(name='Random_'+'-'+str(n), part=p, dependent=ON)
    a = mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly   
    a.translate(instanceList=('Random_'+'-'+str(n), ), vector=(float(l[0]), float(l[1]), float(l[2])))
```

If I try to create viewport object without specifying displayed object. Viewport defaults to current displayed object in initial Viewport. I noticed if I change a module from amssembly to any other e.g. Part, I gain speed improvement, but it relies that the part is sufficiently empty. If I have model with parts that are large and complex it is still rather slow on "setting display.." also my milestone is overwritten by "setting display.." by any case.

Comment: can you show a simple example script? I do a lot os abaqus scripting and have never seen "setting display"

Comment: What happens if you create and switch to a new viewport, without specifying a displayed object?

Comment: what is `milestone`?

Comment: milestone is abaqus function to display a progress in cae or viewer just under the viewport, at the spot where you see "Setting display...". You can find it in Abaqus manual > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Utility commands > Status commands > milestone

Answer (score 2):

I think I've seen this before in a similar situation, where I was creating elements one-by-one in a GUI CAE session. I could not figure out how to disable the screen refresh, and it was maddeningly slow. There were two workarounds:

**1.** Use an alternative command, if one exists, that creates many items at once. In my example above, instead of creating each new element one at a time using the `Element` method, I was able to generate an entire Part and the mesh at once with `makePartFromNodesAndElements` which was significantly faster. In your case, it might be possible to do something similar.

**2.** If you do not need an active GUI, run the script from the system shell: `abaqus cae noGui=script.py`. You can even pass arguments to the script from the command line interface.

Another (untested) possibility I just thought of is that you may be able to create and switch to a new viewport without specifying the displayed object. Then try your code and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: 1. I could not find any alternative command for the function; 2. This is not an options as the code is part of plugin to aid the modeling in assembly; 3. I tried it and the new viewport that is created defaults to current object. However, i noticed that I get speed improvement if I switch to Part module.